# python: get pandas calculate occurence of a common pattern in columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Assume the following table:

```
A   B   C                 D
1   2   [a1,b1,c1]        "abcd"
3   4   [d,e,f]           "qqq"
5   6   [a1,b1,c1,d]      "www"
7   8   [a1,b1,c1,d1,d2]  "abba"
9  10   [a1,b1,c1,c1]     "ppp"
```

Is there a way in `Pandas` to find common pattern in columns and return it? Example: in the table above column C has items with the common pattern `[a1,b1,c1]`, so I would like `pandas` calculate occurences of such pattern across the whole dataframe.

Does Panda support this?

Comment: what is your expected output for this dataframe?

Comment: This is so so broad it's even hard to explain why it's so broad

Comment: @ansev, something like this (I'm making this up):  `df.C.pattern('my_pattern')`  This returns counters per every row where `my_pattern` has occurred in column C. Does it make sense?

Comment: for example `[0,0,1,1,0]` for 'abcd'?